# MediaWiki API not working in Android 9 (api 28) after

Tags: jquery, wikipedia-api

I'm testing a sample JS code (http://jsfiddle.net/gautamadude/dW7Rn/) to get images and other info. using MediaWiki api in android studio 4.1.1. It worked in emulator using api 25, 26 & 27, but not 28 after. Does anybody know the reason?

```css
#imgs img {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getImage()">
   <div id="imgs"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function getImage() {
  var page = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor";
  var title = page.split("/");
  title = title[title.length - 1];

  //Images and their licencing

  $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=" + title +
    "&prop=images&format=json&callback=?",
    function(data) {
      var imgsHtml = "";
      for (img in data["parse"]["images"]) {
        $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:" + data["parse"]
          ["images"][img] +
          "&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&meta=siteinfo&siprop=rightsinfo&format=json&callback=?",
          function(data) {
            for (n in data["query"]["pages"]) {
              imgsHtml += "<img src=\"" + data["query"]["pages"][n]["imageinfo"][0]["url"] + "\">  <
                br > < a href = 'http:"+data["query"]["rightsinfo"].url+"' > "+data["
              query "]  ["rightsinfo"].text + "</a><br><br><br>";
            };
            $("#imgs").html(imgsHtml);
          });
      }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I realised that the mediawiki api used in this code above is an old one which is not working for the new android version. I have to use the new api-Wikimedia REST API (https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/) to get the result. After some testing in android studio, it worked both in the old android api and the new api. Cheers.